# Force textbox databinding update before saving item to database

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have a problem with databinding. The databinding of a textbox in UWP in particular.

**Introduction**
I have a class which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface by means of the abstract class [`ContextBase`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-networkhelper/blob/master/DemoApps/QuizGame/Common/BindableBase.cs), as mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) post. See example code below:

```cs
public class Test : BindableBase
{
    public Test() { }
    
    private string testString;
    public string TestString
    {
        get => testString;
        set => SetProperty(ref testString, value);
    }
}
```

I would then create a page with a textbox data bound to this property to be able to edit the text like this:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind testObject.TestString, mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**The problem**
The `TestString` property only gets updated once the textbox loses focus, however not right away.

I notice this because I have also a `Save` button on this page, which saves the item to a database. When clicking this button when the textbox is unfocused, everything is saved without problem. However, when the textbox is still focused, the old value is saved to the database.

**What I have tried**

- I have tried using the focusmanager to set the focus of the textbox to `Unfocused`, however per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.focus?view=winrt-19041) documentation, `Unfocused` is not allowed and causes an exception.
  It is suggested to move the focus to another control, however when trying this the focus is indeed moved to another control, a textblock (which is also databound to the `TestString` property) gets updated, however the database still contains the old value.
- Trying to change the tabindex also did not seem to do anything.
- Using the text of the database to manually set the value in code behind would destroy the reason you would use databinding in the first place, not mentioning the fact that the focused control sometimes is a numberbox, passwordbox, etc.

I don't want to show a contentdialog/inappnotification each time a textbox is still active, since that will reduce workflow and becomes irritating since it will occur quite often.

**How would I achieve first updating the databinding of the property to the new value before it gets saved to the database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The TestString property only gets updated once the textbox loses focus, however not right away.

By default, changes to `TextBox.Text` are sent to a two-way bound source when the TextBox loses focus.

UWP binding system contains [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger?view=netcore-3.1) property, please set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` like the following, TestString property will updated when you typing.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind testObject.TestString ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

For more please refer [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) document.